# Unable to create a manifest resource name error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've created a Form1.cs in a Windows Forms application, and there's already a file Form1.resx. But whenever I try to run my application, I'm constantly getting the following error:

> Unable to create a manifest resource name for "....\gg\Form1.resx". Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\gg\Form1.cs'.

Could anyone please tell me a reason, and how can I overcome my problem?

Comment: Have you tried saving, closing Visual Studio, and re-opening it again? That sometimes magically fixes difficult-to-trace errors.

Comment: Have you "cleaned" the project sometimes this can help. Also - did you happen to delete an existing Form1 and then add it again - this can cause problems too...

Comment: If nothing helps, you can try recreating the form, based on your from designer code, by pieces, or just copy/paste the controls, depending on which would be faster for your setup.

Answer (score 19):

Your .csproj is corrupted. You need to manually edit it. For a form, there must be 3 entries:

```
<Compile Include="MyForm.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>

<Compile Include="MyForm.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

<EmbeddedResource Include="MyForm.resx">
  <DependentUpon>MyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Answer (score 9):

This is my project..

[image: my project]
[project pic](http://chameleon.zz.mu/temp_photos/Capture.JPG)

Look at SalesSoListReportTest.cs and SalesSoListReportTest.aspx
there are warning icons beside  it..
Try to delete warning files, and re-add.. 
You can find the files at recycle bin..
delete, and re-add the files

Answer (score 3):

It basically means it can't find your files. 
1. Try to close and reopen the project.
2. Re-add the files via Add -> Existing item.

Answer (score 1):

best to run solutions away from desktop. (and "Document and Settings" folder). try moving your solution folder to C:\Projects\ or smth and try again and see if it fixes it.

or if you are not using any resources in your form, then remove it (from project), when you need it will get added automatically next time

Comment: This helped me, I was running my project from a long named network share

Answer (score 1):

If you use TFS this error means created file not found, try copy manually files from creator and paste in your forms folder. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

After rolling back updates to an application that involved the deletion of new source files that had been created in the rolled back Changesets; the Rebuild generated "Unable to create a manifest resource name" errors for those deleted source files.

This was resolved by applying the "Exclude from Project" option on the applicable deleted source files. After doing that, the Rebuild ran without errors.

Answer (score -1):

Just ReOpen the file ,clean & rebuild it and it will be fine.