# Unable to create a manifest resource name for

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've made a git rebase from master on the branch I'm working and after that every time I try to build my project it doesn't, and is showing me an error message, actually is showing several error messages but I think they are related to this one:

> Unable to create a manifest resource name for
>   Migrations\24534563454_SomeFile.resx. Could not find file
>   'SomePath\MyProject\Migrations\24534563454_SomeFile.cs'

I've restarted VS, clean my project and rebuild it but the error persists.. maybe this has to do with the `.csproj` file? What should I do?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942332/unable-to-create-a-manifest-resource-name-error-in-visual-studio-2008), I think you rebase has corrupted some files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942332/unable-to-create-a-manifest-resource-name-error-in-visual-studio-2008) suggested by @kennyzx in the comment and the responses on that link, I saw that there was a yellow warning icon in the file within the `Migrations` folder in the `Solution Explorer`. I deleted that file and now it built correctly