# After rename windows form in C#, the form is not loading & showing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Form1.resx". Could not find file 'C:\Users\S902268\source\repos\BankingApplication\BankingApplication\Form1.cs'. BankingApplication

Comment: Thoughts on it; Look in the folder of the project. What files do you have that are the old and new name with any extension? Are all the files the new name( FormNew.cs, FormNew.Designer.cs, FormNew.resx etc) or if any are the old, rename them. Next, look in the csproj file for any mention of the old name and change it to the new, or use some good text editor like Sublime to do a Find In Files for the old name, in all files in the entire project, for the old name and change them to the new. Lastly, does the resx file it complain about actually exist on disk (old or new name) or has it gone?

Comment: For future.. how did you rename the form? With the solution explorer in visual studio, or by windows explorer renaming a file? Or something else?

Comment: Why are you using Windows Forms in a web application? Or did you mean Web Forms?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942332/unable-to-create-a-manifest-resource-name-error-in-visual-studio-2008) can help you?

Comment: I have seen this myself, in my case it was the .xaml file which was still referring the old names. 
So your files are correctly renamed, the .xaml.cs has been correctly handled but your xaml document still define your Page/UserControl/Window with the old name..  correct it there manually and everything will go smooth again

Answer (score 0):

1. Create project
2. Rename form
3. Save project and close
4. Go to folder where you saved project and open .sln file
5. Thank me ! :)